# Python import error "DLL load failed" | Python

Tags: python, django, iis, isapi

**I'm serving a Django app behind IIS6 web server.**

The test server runs perfectly, but when running behind the web server a module failes to import I get this error:

> Error loading pyodbc module: **DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found**

---

Just for the record the module is [pyodbc](http://pyodbc.sourceforge.net/)

The site is served though isapi by using [isapi-wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/)

---

**Any ideas? It would really make my day! :)**

Comment: I have no answer only that after spending a huge amount of time both googling and trying myself I had to give up on using IIS.  However, it's running fine using apache instead.

Comment: Have you checked with dependencywalker if all dlls are ok?

Comment: I have the same issue: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.` when `import pyodbc` on a Windows 10 machine. I am new with windows - how do I check the dependencies with dependencywalker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is a PITA: it is often caused by missing symbols in dll (because a dependent dll was not found, etc...). You should check the .pyd with dependency walker, or look into the windows log which may log such errors depending on your configuration.

Comment: That helped a lot. For me the missing DLLs were: MSVCR90.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL, WER.DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been battling with setting up Django/Python on IIS 7 on Windows 2008 with MS SQL 2008. I bumped into the same problem as you did. I was using PyODBC-2.1.8. I compiled the modules from source. I used the `mingw` compiler to compile them from source. Nothing worked.

I then downgraded to PyODBC-2.1.7. And it worked! I used the binary available from the site for the Python 2.6 distribution (that is the version of Python I am using).

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had installed pyodbc for 64-bits on a 32-bit OS. Both versions are [available here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc).

I'm hoping I'm not the only one stupid enough to do this and this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

dowload the latest "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" from the links at

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads